# Warning emails on configuration error in managed package

Tags: apex, email

I want to notify the system admin of an org when there are some critical errors in the managed package due to configuration issues. I wanted to know what is the best way to send warning emails. I came across an attribute 'Send Apex Warning Emails' but not sure if this should be used for sending error notifications. Should I be asking for an input for the email of the user to be notified or is there a system admin email for an org?

Comment: One idea is to use custom setting, where user can subscribe for email alerts by adding their email ids

Comment: What about a checkbox on the user record? If checked you could obtain their email address and warning emails can be distributed.